# Has anyone used PHP on Heroku?

Tags: php, heroku

The Celadon Cedar stack supports it for FB development...is there anything special about using it for non-FB development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHP on the Cedar stack for non-FB development.  The only hard requirement I've encountered is that the root of your repository should contain an `index.php` file so that Heroku will detect the presence of a PHP app during the build process.

If the default configuration doesn't suit your needs, you should check out the [heroku-buildpack-php](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php).  Also consider adding a `.htaccess` or `php.ini` file to your repo for more basic configuration tweaks.

Comment: Correct - Heroku will work with PHP but officially Heroku will only support PHP Facebook applications at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the details, I also found this link which is walking me through it: http://cloudspring.com/build-your-app-in-the-cloud-with-heroku-and-the-facebook-sdk/

Answer (score 0):

Google says yes:

http://www.quora.com/Is-there-anything-like-Heroku-I-can-use-for-a-PHP-site/answer/John-Barton-2

Comment: Thanks, I know you can use it for non-FB stuff, I just want to know if there are any limitations or differences from how Heroku is normally used for languages like RoR and Java.